# Use Variable in place of Columns

Tags: vba, variables

I am editing this code that I recorded, and I'm wondering how do I replace the Columns("A:A") with the variable i

The code is to select each column in turn and sort from largest to smallest.

I'm using the i to iterate through the columns. The issue is that I'm not sure how to convert the code that currently references range A1, or range A:A to instead use column i.

```
Sub sort_largest()

Dim i As Long

i = 1 + 1

Do Until Cells(1, i) = ""




Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").Sort.SortFields.clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:A")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Providing `i` is greater than 0 you can use `Columns(i).Select`, but I'd avoid using `Select`.

Comment: You can just remove that `Columns("A:A").Select` completely. It does nothing. Perhaps you are wanting to dynamically change the `Key:=Range("A1")` to use `i` or `.SetRange Range("A:A")` to use `i`? Not sure what you are wanting to have happen here so it's tough to say.

Comment: Yep sorry, that's correct. I'm interested in learning how I change those pieces of code to reference i.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick rewrite using your variable instead of hard coded ranges:

```
Sub sort_largest()

    Dim i As Long

    i = 2
    Do Until Cells(1, i) = ""

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").Sort.SortFields.clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Cells(1, i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").Sort
            .SetRange Columns(i)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

The trickiest bit is switching out `Range("A1")` since your columns in the loop, in variable `i`, are numeric. Instead, you can reference that range using the very handy `Cells()` object which takes two parameters: the numeric row and the numeric column. So `Range("A1")` is the same as `Cells(1, 1)` then we can just swap out that second `1` with the variable.

p.s. I didn't test this so it may not be 100%, but I think it will work fine.